# перевести в Unix time javascript

Tags: javascript

```
date: '2018-09-19T18:28:05+03:00',
```

получаю дату в таком виде,
как перевести в Unix вид ?

Comment: почему удалил )?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Вас формат даты [ISO_8601](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), там есть много популярных форматов, у вас конкретно `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss` + смещение часового пояса, JS такое отлично парсит.

Если в милисекундах:

```js
console.log(+new Date('2018-09-19T18:28:05+04:00'))
```

Если в Unix time то еще разделить на 1000 чтобы получить секунды:

```js
console.log(+new Date('2018-09-19T18:28:05+03:00') / 1000)
```